# One or two paths in a two node complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

This is a basic question, but imagine a complete graph with 2 nodes only and one line or vertex between those two nodes. The graph is undirected. Do you have 1 path or 2 paths in this graph?

EDIT: I meant edge, not vertex

Comment: Vertex=Node so you can't really have a complete graph with two nodes, but "one line or vertex."

Comment: THe reason I ask was that my understanding of Graph theory was that there is one path between two nodes in an undirected path

Comment: I just did an assignment for a Comp Sci course where I was suppose to look over a proof and make corrections on the proof where it was wrong. So I made the correction to the proof thinking that there is one path, but I was told by the professor that in fact there are two paths between two nodes, one for each direction. I can't tell if I am just totally wrong or the professor gave an ambiguous Math problem. I don't care about marks, but I need to know.

Comment: It depends on your definition of path.  Beyond the issue of direction, there is also a question of whether a single node with no edges constitutes a path.

Comment: Path can be defined as an alternating sequence of vertices and edges, as a sequence of vertices or as a subgraph. In any case a path consisting of a single vertex is usually valid. So the right answer may be $1$, $2$, $3$ or $4$ depending on the exact definition

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help, I got a little obsessive and reread a lot of Graph Theory and it seems to be correct. I was suppose to read that paths are sequences, assume ordered, the know that that meant two paths between two points. Anyway, thanks